# Is there a way to get list of Admin Consent Requests using Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We would like to validate the Admin Consent Request before giving admin consent to an Application.
Is there a way to use Graph API to get the list of admin consent requests?

We will require an API for both the Delegated and Application permission consent request list.

Comment: An admin would get a screen listing all the consent requested by the application. Its not clear what the expected behavior is.

Comment: I want to get through API. Is this possible?

Comment: Currently, it is not possible to get this information via API. Please raise the [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to get this information via API. Please raise the [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)