# Microsoft graph, fetching app permissions based on appId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

Azure AD: I want to fetch delegated as well as application permissions/consent based on appId.

Comment: Is there any graph API which checks the permissions as per the Application Id?

Comment: Please refer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437748/is-there-a-way-to-get-list-of-admin-consent-requests-using-graph-api) it may help you

Comment: Are you looking for programming or particular in Graph?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity yes I am looking for programming..want collect info like apps require different  permissions and consent on the basis of application Id

Comment: To Get all permissions granted to an app in Azure AD. Please refer to [this](https://gist.github.com/psignoret/9d73b00b377002456b24fcb808265c23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Lists delegated permission grants (OAuth2PermissionGrants) and application permissions grants (AppRoleAssignments) granted to an app in Azure Ad. Please use  this [script](https://gist.github.com/psignoret/9d73b00b377002456b24fcb808265c23)

Comment: Thanks, your link helped me to reach my goal, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants?$filter=clientId eq '{ObjectId}'"